# AmpScript to select Right or Left characters from a string

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there an AmpScript function that can be used in an equivalent manner to sql left, right and mid functions?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Substring function](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Substring) to get the same result.

> ## Substring(S1, I1, I2)
>
> Returns the portion of the specified string
>   starting with the specified character position and no longer than the
>   specified length. If the specified character position is greater than
>   the length of the specified string, an empty string is returned.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - S1    The string from which to return a portion
> - I1    The character position at which to begin the substring
> - I2    Maximum length of the substring Example
>
> `%%=Substring("abcdef",2,2)=%%`
>   System returns:
>
> bc

SQL `Left` has the syntax:

```
LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
```

The following should return the first two characters from input string.

```
%%=Substring("abcdefg",1,2)=%%
```

SQL `Right` has the syntax:

```
RIGHT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
```

The following should return the last two characters from input string.

```
%%=Substring("abcdefg",Length("abcdefg") - 2,2)=%%
```

SQL `Mid` has the syntax:

```
MID( character_expression , start, length)
```

The following should return the two characters starting from the second in the input string.

```
%%=Substring("abcdefg",2,2)=%%
```

Comment: %%=Substring("abcdefg",Length("abcdefg") - 2,2)=%% gives me an error, it's something with the "-" sign.

Comment: Thy this: %%=Substring("abcdefg",subtract(Length("abcdefg"),1),2)=%% - two changes - (1) we need to use "subtract" to calculate the length minus the characters to work backwards; (2) we need to subtract one fewer than the number of right side characters we want to display.