# AMPscript Substring to capture last characters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I tried applying the method someone posted here

[AmpScript to select Right or Left characters from a string](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44662/ampscript-to-select-right-or-left-characters-from-a-string) but "-"

gives me an error in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

This is my code:

```
Set @creditcardnumberlastfour = Substring(@creditcardnumber,Length(@creditcardnumber)-4,4)=%%
```

I try to capture the last 4 characters. What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AMPScript does not recognize '-' as subtract, you need to use the [SUBTRACT()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/subtract/) function to accomplish this. (Also, you have the =%% tail on this, when it needs to reside inside of an ampscript block)

See below:

```
%%[

Set @cardnumberlastfour = Substring(@cardnumber, SUBTRACT(Length(@cardnumber), 3), 4)

]%%
```

---

**EDIT**
Adding some extra context as requested by @kcalero:

Below is taken from [AMPScript Guide](https://ampscript.guide/substring/) to show the arguments for the function:
[image]

Basically what I am doing in the above is:

1. Taking the string (`@cardnumber`)  and placing it into the first argument.
2. Using math,`SUBTRACT()`, I find the starting point. For this case since I want to only take the last 4 characters, I take the Length of the string and then subtract 4 from it.  Basically, if length is 8, then I use math to set the start point at 8 - 4 = 4. This is then used as the second argument.
3. The final argument is the length of the substring you want to use. E.g. since we want the last 4, we need this to be 4.

@kcalero - I would do the following:

```ampscript
%%[
    set @string = 'abcdefg'
    set @strLength = Length(@string)
    set @subLength = 2
    set @subStart = Subtract(@strLength,Subtract(@subLength,1))

    set @lastTwoChar = Substring(@string,@subStart,@subLength)
]%%

%%=v(@lastTwoChar)=%%
```

**OUTPUT**: `fg`
This will also give you a reusable script that you can change the string and `@subLength` to get different lengths of characters without having to change anything else.

Comment: No problem! If you find that this is the correct solution, please be sure to click the checkmark next to it to allow others to reference this if anyone has the same issue.

Comment: checkmarked right away, thanks again, works like a charm!

Comment: @gortonington can't quite get this to work in the way you have it. Trying to understand what the last two numbers are, but can't figure it out. Can you please describe what they represent?

Comment: @kcalero - I added more context to my answer and a different script that may help you to better understand and customize.

Comment: Your example actually gives the result "ef" and not "fg". @subStart will be 5. So the substring will start from "e", and not "f"

Comment: @user3274635 - thanks for the heads up, I have adjusted my answer. That is what I get for rushing and not double checking my work.