# AMPScript if Substring equals X

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying the below code so that if the last character of the string is S, then a variable will equal to Z. Am currently getting an error :( Appreciate your help

```
%%[
SET @EndswithS = Substring(@Name, SUBTRACT(Length(@Name), 1), 225)
IF @EndswithS = 's' THEN SET @nameend = 'Z'
ELSE SET @nameend = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 2):

I broke it down a little, so it's easier for you to understand how this works:

```
%%[
set @name = [set name here]
set @namelenght = Length(@name)
SET @EndswithS = Substring(@name,@namelenght,1)
IF @EndswithS == 's' THEN 
 SET @nameend = 'Z'
ELSE SET @nameend = 'Y'
ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested using the answers provided [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44662/ampscript-to-select-right-or-left-characters-from-a-string) and on this thread.

> The following should return the last two characters from input string.

```
%%=Substring("abcdefg",Length("abcdefg") - 2,2)=%%
```

However the minus in "-2" does not work and need to use Subtract.

Here is my final code.

```
%%[

SET @Name = Name
SET @NameLength = Length(@Name)
SET @EndswithS = Substring(@Name, Subtract(Length(@Name),0),1)
SET @EndS = Substring(@Name, Subtract(Length(@Name),1),1)

IF @EndswithS == 's' THEN
 SET @nameend = 'Z'
 ELSE SET @nameend = 'Y'
 
ENDIF
]%%
```

In my code the `@EndswithS` selects the 1st character from end, where as `@EndS` selects the 2nd character from end.